# ScrollView Focus LinearLatout or others elements

Tags: android, focus, scrollview

Have an activity with a ScrollView when an item selected, you turn to another layout in View.Visible, or vice versa, but when I select an item that is a bit down, as is state 3 image, losing half information, forcing the user to have to move your finger.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/3CV03LG.png]

The question is: How I can do that LinearLayout requestFocus?

- Note: I already close layouts, I just need the focus.

I've tried

Google : Android ScrollView focus edittext / elements / layout / onclick focus scroll , but not work .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save last opened *LinearLayout* in variable and close it after user open new.
Or show more code.

**EDIT**

Use *scrollToView(View view, ScrollView scrollView)*, where *view* is your *LinearLayout*. *LinearLayout* will take the maximum possible space in *ScrollView*

```
public static void scrollToView(View view, ScrollView scrollView) {
        scrollToView(view, scrollView, 0);
    }


    public static void scrollToView(final View view, final ScrollView scrollView, int count) {
        if (view != null && view != scrollView) {
            count += view.getTop();
            scrollToView((View) view.getParent(), scrollView, count);
        } else if (scrollView != null) {
            final int finalCount = count;

            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    scrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, finalCount);
                }
            }, 200);
        }
    }
```

Comment: you've seen that I put note ?

Comment: pfff.. you are so .. great